# How to make one div appear and rest all hide after certain time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a survey evaluation box on a quiz lander.

I am new to jquery and javascript. But I managed to create the questions and all steps.

I have 4 questions and After that evaluation box appears. The after evalve box is shown (div id=Evalve) it shows...

Question 1 valid...and after 1 second...question 2 valid...and so on.

So can I get some help?

I am not able to build some logical steps that could workout. So please, I really appreciate any help from you guys.

I am trying to model this type of page.

Link: http://courses.healthshul.com/test1/

after clicking on 4th question I want to emulate the evalve box that shows up.

Thanks in advance for your precious time.

Comment: Use settimeout function

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score -1):

Use the Jquery [remove()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_remove.asp) function to delete all divs in your page. 
You can loop through the divs, and remove them all, after they are removed. 
[Create a new element](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp) in Jquery and append it or insert it to the body element.

If you don't want to remove them all, and keep one div rather than creating a new one, just write an if statement to check for the div id inside the loop, if it matches to the one you don't want to remove, just ['continue'](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_continue.asp) and do nothing.